# Is there a way to map array_of_scalars data type from MongoDb to postgresql?

Tags: java, mongodb, postgresql, etl, database-migration

I am currently working on a data-engineering project that is crucial to my business. I am trying to migrate data from MongoDB to a postgresql warehouse and I am using the streamer in this [repo](https://github.com/sbrichardson/mongo-postgresql-streamer).

I have created the mapping file and everything is working well, except for the `_ARRAY_OF_SCALARS` datatype, it's showing as null values in the table that is created for the array along with `_Creation_date` column which is also showing null values.

The following code snippet is the one mapping an array from MongoDB to the postgresql:

```
tablename:{

    "favorit_by_customers": {
        "dest":"favorited_by_customers",
        "type": "_ARRAY_OF_SCALARS",
        "fk": "favorited_by_customers_id",
        "valueField":"thevalueIwant"
    },
    "favorited_by_customers":{
        "pk": "id_number",
        "id_number": {
            "dest": "id_number",
            "type": "TEXT"
        },

        "thevalueIwant":{
            "type":"TEXT"
        }
    }
}
```

The number of rows in the postgresql shows that the streamer was able to identify the right number of items in the array in all documents, but it shows null values. Has anyone used it or used something similar and can help?

P.S: As a data professional I am familiar with python but not with java which makes editing the source code challenging.

I tried changing the data type of the resulting column to integer, while I know that is string datatype, and the streamer didn't throw an error which means it doesn't access the values in the array.